# Accessing one element in an array using Firebase-collection in polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer

I am trying to use the new firebase-collection introduced in Polymer 1.0 to access one element in an array in my firebase nosql database. However, I get back nothing.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<firebase-collection data="{{testItem}}"
  location="https://<firebase-path>.firebaseio.com/testItems/0/">
</firebase-collection>

  <section class="layout vertical center-center" id="moreInfo">
    <div class="layout vertical">
      <test-block art="{{testItem}}"></test-block>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Notice how I am trying to access item at index 0 in https:///firebaseio.com/testItems. Is it even possible to access it using firebase-collection? Or should we just fetch the collection and then iterate?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that approach won't work since the data property expects/is populated with an array of data from your DB. I believe if you set the location to "https://.firebaseio.com/testItems" that you can reference the first item in the data array like so:

```
<test-block art="{{testItem.0}}"></test-block>
```

Another approach if you know the Firebase key of the item you want would be to use firebase-collection's getByKey method in your Javascript.